# Php - Search a string in cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I set cookie with php, using

```
setcookie("name", "John Mayer", time()+31556926 , "/");
```

After, I want to search Cookie value with php to check if it includes a value, using

```
if (strpos($_COOKIE["name"],"Mayer")) {
```

However, it always returns false. Is it not allowed to check cookie value with php ? If so is there anyway to check it ?

Comment: why you added , "/" in the end of sitting a cookie, once I removed it everything worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Actually strpos returns a index so,if string matched from initial then it returns 0 which is zero and considered as false. It returns -1 if search text didnot matched, so you can make a condition like-

```
  if (strpos($_COOKIE["name"],"Mayer")>=0)
  {

  }
  // or strict comparison with false
  if (strpos($_COOKIE["name"],"Mayer")!==false)
  {

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
if (strpos($_COOKIE["name"],"Mayer") !== false) {
```

[PHP strpos manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 1):

You edit your code.

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE["name"]) && !empty($_COOKIE["name"])) {
    if (strpos($_COOKIE["name"], 'Mayer') !== false) {
      echo 'exists';
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

Answer (score 1):

check if its set and proceed

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE["name"])) {

if (strpos($_COOKIE["name"], 'Mayer') !== false) {
    // it exists
        echo 'true';
    }

    }
```

Comment: Your "isset" logic is backwards.